# Naming conventions - HTML elements in JS

Tags: javascript, html, naming-conventions

How do I name the HTML element objects in JS?

`var divEditorArea = document.getElementById("editorarea");`

`var btnCheckSyntax = document.getElementById("checksyntax");`

Is this a good way?

Comment: if you give them the correct id then... yeah... what do you need again?

Comment: people seem to have done away with the type prefix on element references... so you would just use `editorArea` and `checkSyntax`

Comment: @Ibu: I just asked if this is a good way of naming js objects, So I can follow that convention for the whole codebase. Please read the question before posting a comment.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no convention for naming HTML elements in JS. Javascript is such a diverse world that even if there was a convention, it would hardly be followed by the majority of the community. See, for example, the variety of code linters and code style conventions there are (https://www.sitepoint.com/comparison-javascript-linting-tools/).

Names should show your intentions clearly, so that code is easily understandable. I don't think that adding the type of the HTML element to the JS variable names is of much use for clarity purposes (the 'btn' and 'div' in you example), but there could be cases where it adds clarity. And, if you are in a team, you probably should follow the team's conventions.

Use your best judgement and always strive for clarity in your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you use vanilla JS, as Vinicius told there is no convention for naming JS variables for HTML DOM elements.

I would name them as:

```
let elCheckSyntax = document.querySelector("#checksyntax");

OR

let elementEditorArea and elementCheckSyntax
```

another way would be some team like to prefix the DOM elements with $. So as soon as anybody in the team sees any variable prefixed with $ they know it's a DOM element.

like this

```
let $editorArea;
let $checkSyntax;
```

so, it totally depends on your convenient if you work independently and your team's naming convention